# jQueryの横スクロールイベントについて

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jqueryを利用して、一定値を超えた場合にクラスを変更する処理を行いたいと考えています。

やりたい事
１：画面を横720px以下に縮小場合に、指定CSSを設定
２：画面を横721px以上にした場合も指定CSSを設定

確認したい点
画面を縮小した場合はイベントが発火するのですが、拡大した場合にイベントが発火しない為、どなたかご教授いただければ幸いです。

````html
```
<body>
  <div class="tabbody">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="w-5" id="tr-no">No.</th>
          <th class="w-10">ステータス</th>
          <th class="w-25">テストコード</th>
          <th class="w-40" id="tr-agency-name">支店名</th>
          <th class="w-25" id="last-update">最終更新日時</th>
          <th class="w-10 tcenter" >チェック</th>
          <th class="" >照会</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <table>
  </div>


</body>
````

```js
$(function() {
 var tabbody = $('.tabbody');

 tabbody.scrollLeft(function () {

  if ($(window).scrollLeft(720) ) {
        console.log("ここは呼び出しされる")
    $('#tr-no').removeClass('w5').addClass('w-7');
    $('#tr-agency-name').removeClass('w40').addClass('w38');
    $('#last-update').removeClass('w15').addClass('w15-7');

  } else if ($(window).scrollLeft(721)) {
     console.log("ここが呼び出しされない")
   $('#tr-no').removeClass('w7').addClass('w-5');
   $('#tr-agency-name').removeClass('w38').addClass('w40');
   $('#last-update').removeClass('w15-7').addClass('w15');
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: 提示頂いたソースで試してみましたが、そもそも縮小も取れていません。scrollLeftはスクロールイベントを検知する関数ではなく、横スクロールの量を参照代入する関数です。scroll()の打ち間違いですか？

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。scrollLeftの認識に誤りがありました。　要件を満たすやり方を再度考えてみます

Comment: 縮小、拡大は、'resize'イベントでは、$(function(){$(window).on('resize',function(){console.log($(window).width());});

Comment: ご指摘の通り.resizeで対応できました　ありがとうございました。

Answer (score -1):

`.scrollLeft`ではなく、`.resize`メソッドで対応しました。